# Having compiled LibVLC .so files for x86 cpu's

Tags: android, libvlc, android-x86

I have an Android application to stream video and audio, which uses the LibVLC sdk.

I took the relevant .java files and .so jni files from the following git:
https://github.com/wass08/VLC-Simple-Player-Android

Now I'm trying to load my application in my Galaxy tablet instead of my Nexus phone, and that causes an exception. After some research I've figured out that I need the LibVLC .so files also for x86 cpu's, or else it won't work.

You've probably noticed that the .so files I have in that git are only for armeabi-v7a, so I need .so files for x86 as well.

I couldn't find them anywhere online, and couldn't compile LibVLC by myself in my PC.
Can anyone help me with providing those missing libraries?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile it by yourself, I assume your PC running Windows, and you have to build it on Linux, so I would recommend you using some kind of vmware just for building.

You can find instructions [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile) but be ready for it not gonna be simple.

Comment: Hi Shem, thanks for the quick reply. I have a VM of Ubuntu in my PC, but where can I find the sources to compile?

Comment: Shem, I'm having an issue when calling compile-libvlc.sh - it seems it tries to download a .tar.gz file from url that returns 404 not found (Ive checked it manually and it's true). What should I do?

Comment: http://live555.com/liveMedia/public/live.2015.12.22.tar.gz it's really doesn't exist since there's a newer version in this folder. Where should I modify it?

Comment: Eventually downloaded it from another place and added it. Thanks